# As left R-modules, is an ideal a homomorphic image of a ring?

Tags: ring-theory, modules, ideals

Let $R$ be a ring, $I\subset R$ a proper ideal. My question is whether there is a $R-$module homomorphism $\phi: R\rightarrow R$ such that $I=im\phi$. We already know that as a left $R-$module, $I$ is a quotient of ***some*** free $R-$module. Will this free module necessarily be $R$ itself?

Comment: Your setting looks strange. You said $I$ is a proper ideal of $R$ and $\phi \colon R \to R$ is a surjective homomorphism; fine. But then $I \subsetneq R = \operatorname{im}\phi$!

Comment: You are right, and I just noticed that. The "surjective" should be deleted, since if $I=im\phi$, then every element in $I$ has a preimage under $\phi$. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is far from true. If there were a surjective $R$-module homomorphism $\phi:R\to I$, then $I$ would be generated over $R$ by the one element $\phi(1)$ (i.e. it would be a principal ideal).

However, you can find ideals $I\subset R$ which are not generated by one element. You can even find ideals which are not generated by any *finite* number of elements (just take any non-Noetherian ring).

For an explicit example, take $R=k[x,y]$ and $I=(x,y)$.